# Erro no GIT ao enviar projeto ao Ionic Pro: fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error: Broken pipe

Tags: ionic, git, ssh, gitlab

Assinei o Ionic Pro e estou tentando enviar meu projeto local para o Cloud deles.

Utilizo o comando:

```
git push ionic master
```

Começa tudo bem mas dá os erros a seguir:

```
git push ionic master
Enter passphrase for key 'C:\Users\Ramos\.ssh\ionic\278626':
Counting objects: 2049, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1996/1996), done.
fatal: Timeout reached(560/2049), 82.85 MiB | 113.00 KiB/s
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedlyB | 98.00 KiB/s
fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error: Broken pipe
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Como posso resolver?

**EDITADO: O que fiz até o momento.**

1. Criei o .gitignore com as pastas que não precisam:

   platforms/
   xdk/
   node_modules/
   hooks/
   .vs/
   .tern-defs/
   .git/
2. Editei o arquivo de configuração do SSH (HOME.ssh\config), como na primeira resposta.
3. Adicionei os seguintes comandos:

   set GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1 
       set GIT_TRACE=1 
       set GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1

Mas o erro continua, assim:

```
Counting objects: 2072, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2016/2016), done.
fatal: Timeout reached(2039/2072), 80.37 MiB | 93.00 KiB/s
Wfriting objects:  98% (2039/2072), 80.50 Miatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error: Broken pipe
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

O pessoal do Ionic até o momento só disse pra criar o .gitignore que já tinha feito e ver a conexão com internet, que é boa....

Comment: Criou o .gitignore antes ou depois do commit? Porque se foi depois, node_modules ainda esta trackeado..

Comment: Tente `git rm -r --cached .` <- não esqueça do ponto ele faz parte do comando, faça o commit e tenta o push.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sua sessão de SSH "quebrou".

No seu arquivo de configuração do SSH (HOME\.ssh\config) adicione a seguinte linha:

```
ServerAliveInterval 30
```

Isso fará com que o cliente enviei um "OI" para o servidor avisando que a conexão ainda está ativa.

Caso ainda deseje alterar a quantidade de "avisos" que o cliente fará, adicione o seguinte ao seu arquivo de configuração:

```
  ServerAliveCountMax 5
```

Resumindo: O cliente mandará ao servidor a cada 30 segundos durante 5 vezes um aviso de que a sessão ainda está em execução.

Comment: Oi @Diego, fiz as mudanças no arquivo: Host git.ionicjs.com
    IdentityFile C:\Users\Ramos\.ssh\ionic\MEU_CODIGO

ServerAliveInterval 30
ServerAliveCountMax 55

Comment: Aumentei o intervalo, mas mesmo assim não vai. Mesmo com um .gitignore pra não enviar tudo.

Comment: @Ramos Você consegue realizar o push para outros repositórios (locais ou externos)? .. Tenta modificar o buffer seguindo os passos: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842687/the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-while-git-cloning

Comment: Como está utilizando o Windows, execute os seguintes comandos: set GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1
set GIT_TRACE=1
set GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1

Comment: Continua... chega em 98% e dá a mensagem: Wfriting objects:  98% (2039/2072), 80.50 Miatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: Editei a pergunta com tudo o que fiz...

Comment: @Ramos .. Você está utilizando algum proxy? Pergunto isso pois caso tenha, pode ser uma limitação e partiremos para análise nesse lado

Comment: Não, não uso proxy....

Comment: @Ramos tente mudar o tipo de conexão utilizada para o push: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11200237/how-do-i-get-git-to-default-to-ssh-and-not-https-for-new-repositories

Comment: Bem pessoal, depois de muito conversar com o pessoal do Ionic, consegui mandar o projeto. Tive que mandar para um repositório Git para chamar deste outro repositório. Direto não consegui mesmo. Por isso demorei a dar como solucionado aqui. Obrigado a todos.